# Second checkbox depends from another checkbox

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox

I want make second checkbox invisible while first checkbox isn't "checked". In other case i want check my first checkbox and the second should be clickable. How can i do it?

My example doesn't work:

```
if (FirstCheckBox.Checked == true)
{
    SecondCheckBox.Visible = true;
}
else if (FirstCheckBox.Checked == false)
{
    SecondCheckBox.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: Can you show more code? Where is this code running?

Comment: can you share some more details how you are doing so we can  help its not clear

Comment: do you want this changes to appear immediately you check your checkbox, i'd advise you use some javascript

Comment: @AdeoluwaSimeon this is a question about C# not javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the CheckedChanged event.  For example:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    checkBox1.CheckedChanged += CheckBox1_CheckedChanged;
    checkBox2.Enabled = false;
}

//When happens some change in a checkBox1
private void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (checkBox1.Checked)
        checkBox2.Enabled = true;
    else
        checkBox2.Enabled = false;
}
```

The same using lambda expressions:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    checkBox2.Enabled = false;
    checkBox1.CheckedChanged += (s, e) => checkBox2.Enabled = checkBox1.Checked;
}
```